# Qt Catching signal of checkbox to do an action

Tags: c++, qt

In my Qt program, I want to catch the signal of one of my checkbox to know if it's checked or not. I did it :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QtGui>
#include "Window.h"

Window::Window() : QWidget()
{
  setFixedSize(400, 800);

  m_bouton = new QPushButton("Module 1");
  m_bouton->setCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor);

  m_bouton2 = new QPushButton("Module 2");
  m_bouton2->setCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor);

  m_bouton3 = new QPushButton("Module 3");
  m_bouton3->setCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor);

  m_bouton4 = new QPushButton("Module 4");
  m_bouton4->setCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor);

  m_check4 = new QCheckBox(this);
  m_check4->move(300, 50);
  m_check4->setChecked(true);

  m_check3 = new QCheckBox(this);
  m_check3->move(200, 50);
  m_check3->setChecked(true);

  m_check2 = new QCheckBox(this);
  m_check2->move(100, 50);
  m_check2->setChecked(true);

  m_check1 = new QCheckBox(this);
  m_check1->move(0, 50);
  m_check1->setChecked(true);

  QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
  layout->addWidget(m_bouton);
  layout->addWidget(m_bouton2);
  layout->addWidget(m_bouton3);
  layout->addWidget(m_bouton4);
  this->setLayout(layout);
  this->setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 10px;");

  this->setWindowOpacity(0.5);
  QWidget::setWindowFlags(Qt::Tool | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
  QWidget::setWindowTitle("Monitor Core");
  QObject::connect(m_bouton4, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(SizeCHange()));
  QObject::connect(m_check4, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(SizeCHange()));
}

void    Window::SizeCHange()
{
  setFixedSize(400, 800 - 200);
  m_bouton4->setVisible(false);
}
```

and this is my .h :

```
#ifndef _WINDOW_H_
#define _WINDOW_H_

#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QCheckBox>

class Window : public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT

 public:
  Window();

  public slots:
    void SizeCHange();

 private:
    QPushButton *m_bouton;
    QPushButton *m_bouton2;
    QPushButton *m_bouton3;
    QPushButton *m_bouton4;
    QCheckBox *m_check1;
    QCheckBox *m_check2;
    QCheckBox *m_check3;
    QCheckBox *m_check4;
};

#endif
```

This is working but just one time. I want to know if it's check or not, then I will be able to resize my window and make something invisible as I want.

Comment: Strange behavior. This code works fine for me. Can you give a larger piece of code? How are m_check4 and m_bouton4 defined ?

Comment: This code works fine for me. Did you do the **Rebuild** of your project? What IDE, OS and Qt version do you use ?

Comment: What does it mean "working but just one time" ? If you want to know is your checkbox checked or not, why don't you call **isChecked()** ?

Comment: Do I have to call isChecked for the signal ?
My goal is to do : if it's check, button4 is visible and window takes a size, when it's uncheck, the button4 become invisible and the window reduces itself. So I think I need to create a new signal but I don't really know how, because isChecked takes a bool I think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to use a bool parameter, which indicates the state of the checkbox:

```
public slots:
    void SizeCHange(bool checked); //using bool parameter

//...
QObject::connect(m_check4, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(SizeCHange(bool)));
//...
void Window::SizeCHange(bool checked)
{
    if(checked)
    {
        setFixedSize(400, 800 - 200);
    }
    else
    {
        // removing fixed size
        setMinimumSize(QSize(0, 0));
        setMaximumSize(QSize(QWIDGETSIZE_MAX, QWIDGETSIZE_MAX));
    }
    m_bouton4->setVisible(checked);
}
```

[The docs for a signal **clicked()**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked)

Comment: This is the idea, there is just a small problem, the first time you uncheck, it does not resize the window as (400, 800 - 200). And when we check it, it should make reapear the m_button4 and set the size as it was before